# How to show Alert dialog after processbar dialog dismiss?

Tags: java, android

i want to show alert dialog after processbar dialog dismis (cick on listview to show processbar) :
this is my code show processbar dialog:

```
ProgressDialog barProgressDialog;
Handler updateBarHandler;

public void launchBarDialog(View view)
{
    barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    barProgressDialog.setTitle("Processing,please wait ...");
    barProgressDialog.setMessage("Cracking password in progress ...");
    barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(barProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    barProgressDialog.setMax(10);
    barProgressDialog.show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Here you should write your time consuming task...
                while (barProgressDialog.getProgress() <= barProgressDialog.getMax()) {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            barProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(2);
                          }
                      });
                    if (barProgressDialog.getProgress() == barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
                        barProgressDialog.dismiss();


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }).start();




}
```

Please post sample code. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: u should use thread time that's depends on u ....10000,etc seconds

Comment: you can do similar to how you did the progressbar increment. Create a new handler which can create an alert when invoked. Call this handler just after you dismiss the progressbar.

Comment: please give me sample example! thank you

Comment: use listeners, cleanest way i think

Comment: how can use listerner, please give more detail, code. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the interface DialogInterface.OnDismissListener on method **setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener listener):AlertDialog.** It will help you to do what you need. The code below will help you to do what you need.

```
ProgressDialog barProgressDialog;
Handler updateBarHandler;

public void launchBarDialog(View view) {
    updateBarHandler = new Handler();
    barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    barProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            //Put your AlertDialog Here ....
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setMessage("This Alert Dialog will be show after the ProgressDialog dismissed");
            alert.show();

        }
    });
    barProgressDialog.setTitle("Processing,please wait ...");
    barProgressDialog.setMessage("Cracking password in progress ...");
    barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(barProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    barProgressDialog.setMax(10);
    barProgressDialog.show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Here you should write your time consuming task...
                while (barProgressDialog.getProgress() <= barProgressDialog
                        .getMax()) {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            barProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(2);

                            if (barProgressDialog.getProgress() == barProgressDialog
                                    .getMax()) {
                                barProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("thiago", "error when trying to run the Thread==>"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I hope that code help you to solve your problem. :)

Comment: yeah, this is best answer, i did it. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

You just need to place

```
updateBarHandler = new Handler();
```

Here is a complete example of what you need:

[http://turboprogramacion.blogspot.cl](http://turboprogramacion.blogspot.cl/2016/02/android-dialogs-como-crear-un.html)